# Fork child process terminates with signal 0

Tags: c, signals, fork

I have a small function that should give me information about how a child process finished.

```
int debug_wait() {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        printf("failed with signal %d (%s)\n", sig, strsignal(sig));
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("ended in an unexpected way\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following result:

```
double free or corruption (out)
tests failed with signal 0 (Unknown signal 0)
```

I know I should fix my code, but why do I get signal no. 0? Is there a mistake in my function or does it have an other meaning?

Since people asked, here is a example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int debug_wait() {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        printf("tests failed with signal %d (%s)\n", sig, strsignal(sig));
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("tests ended in an unexpected way\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    void* ptr = malloc(10);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        free(ptr);
        free(ptr);
    }
    else {
        debug_wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: “double free or corruption” — fix this problem **first.** This is a memory error. Memory errors can cause unexpected behavior in other parts of your program, so you should fix memory errors first.

Comment: This is from the child process, I want to find out why it gets terminated with signal 0. The double free is intentional in this context.

Comment: can you provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example of what you're doing here?  Sounds like you're starting a child, double freeing, then expecting to be able to pick up the resultant exit signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are decoding the wrong thing. If `WIFSIGNALED` is `true` you can use `WTERMSIG` and `WCOREDUMP` (check `#ifdef WCOREDUMP` first). To decude the `WSTOPSIG` then `WIFSTOPPED` must be `true`.

Example:

```c
int status;
pid_t pid = wait(&status);
if (pid == -1) return 1;

if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("normal exit %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));

} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    printf("termsig %d core dump=%c\n", WTERMSIG(status),
            WCOREDUMP(status) ? 'Y' : 'N');

} else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
    printf("stop %d cont=%c\n", WSTOPSIG(status),
           WIFCONTINUED(status) ? 'Y' : 'N');
}
```

Without using the feature test macros:

```c
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("normal exit %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));

} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    printf("termsig %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));

} else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
    printf("stop %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like I misunderstood the manual page

Comment: And now I get signal 6 (aborted), which makes sense